# Access to tests between modules

Tags: android, gradle, testing

When trying to add import from child module to test in `commonTest` dependency cannot be found.

Example. Module `base` has class `BaseTest` in `commonTest` . Module `shared` has dependency to `base` in gradle inside of `commonMain` sourceSet. Module `share` has class `Test` in `commonTest`. When trying to import `BaseTest` dependency cannot be found.

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    kotlin("native.cocoapods")
    id("com.android.library")
}

version = "1.0"

kotlin {
    android()
    iosX64()

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(project(":base"))
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting
        val androidTest by getting
        val iosMain by creating {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
        }
        val iosTest by creating {
            dependsOn(commonTest)
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdk = 32
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 32
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.myapplication

import com.example.base.Base
import kotlin.test.Test


class Test {
    @Test
    fun test() {
        Base()
        BaseTest()
    }
}
```

How can I get access to child test classes in child module?